# CSS: vertical center responsive image within 100% height absolute div

Tags: css, html, center, absolute

I'd like to center an image (that changes dimensions according to the screen size) horizontally vertically in a div. That div is positioned absolute and has a height of 100%. Under that div, another div is placed.

I made a [visual example](http://jsfiddle.net/9xZxk/)

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="center">
            <img src="http://www.vilna.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/test.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    You can't see this without scrolling
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to center the test image vertically in the red div.

Thanks!

Comment: my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21919578/1491212

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, (there are many other ways, this is one way of achieving what you described )

http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/9xZxk/4/

I have added this to your css,

```
.img{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:url('http://www.vilna.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/test.jpg') center center no-repeat;     /* this will automatically place your image file centred horizontally and vertically.*/ 
    background-size: 50% auto;
}
#center{
 height:100%;
}
```

And slight modification to your html like this,

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but now the image doesn't scale anymore. The width of the image should adapt to the screen size. Any solution for this?

Comment: have updated the code. now it will resize according to browser width.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sY4dh/ Add background-size property to previous answer/

```
        #div1{
            background-color: red;
            background-image: url('http://www.vilna.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/test.jpg');
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 40% auto;
        }
```